# change edittext bottom line color to tranparent color

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext

How could I change editext buttom line color

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="colorControlNormal">#ff0000</item>
        <item name="colorControlActivated">#ff0000</item>
        <item name="colorControlHighlight">#ff0000</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">#ff0000</item>
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
```

As you see I set it on red but i always show black. What's wrong here?
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Maybe it will work with:

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

It works for me

Answer (score 2):

Add this to your `EditText`

`android:background=@null`

Comment: No it's not a solution

Comment: Works for me. I dont know why it does not work for you. Or you can copy the source code for EditText, and tweak with it.